# Check if an item of one list present in another list of string Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am checking if the state name in `state_list` is present in the `address` list. I tried the following method but it's not working.

```
state_list = ['VIC', 'WA']
address = ['Unit 6, Traeger Court Business Park 28 Thynne', 'Street', 'BRUCE, ACT, 2617', 'AUSTRALIA']

for state in state_list:
    for a in address:
        if state in a:
            print(state)
```

Comment: None of `'VIC', 'WA'` is present in `address` or any of it strings. Why are you surprised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'VIC' 'WA'
```

Neither of them are in your address list

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. You do not have any address in address list which have any state from state list. Add a new address which contains state from state_list and check again